# Passing a predicate function parameter in moq fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, integration-testing, moq, mef

I am trying to use moq to mock a function on my licence class.

The licence class has the following interface:

```
Licence TryGetLicence(Predicate<Licence> filter);
```

In my integration test I am using mef to lazy load objects. My class finds the mef loaded objects and needs to check if there are licences available. For my test I create two objects, one of which can be licenced. I want to use moq to only return a licence for this object and null for the other, just as the real class would. The problem I am having is that moq doesn’t like me passing in a predicate. I’m not sure if moq just doesn’t handle predicates in this way or am I just implementing this wrong?

Here are the lines of code I have in my test that sets up moq for the above interface:

```
var lic = new Licence
{
   LicId = Guid.Parse("53024D4E-3A01-4489-A341-753D04748EB9"),
   LicName = "test",
   Count = 1,
   ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
};

var mockAgent = new Mock<ILicenceAgent>();
mockAgent.Setup(x => x.TryGetLicence (y => y.LicId == lic.LicId)) Returns(lic);
```

This builds but when the last line is hit it throws an Unsupported expression exception.

For other tests I have used:

```
mockAgent.Setup(x => x. TryGetLicence (It.IsAny<Predicate<Licence>>())).Returns(lic);
```

I can’t use this for my new test as it would return a valid licence for both objects I have loaded.

Can moq be used in the way I am trying to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
Predicate<Licence> predicate = y => y.LicId == lic.LicId;
mockAgent.Setup(x => x.TryGetLicence (predicate)).Returns(lic);
```

When you create the predicate inside `Setup` call, lambda expression is evaluated as a part of the expression that will be passed as a parameter. We prevent that by making sure it's only a delegate on the line above.

Comment: Thanks, This does what I needed it to do. Saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 licences - lic1 and lic2, you can setup mock like this:

```
mockAgent.Setup(x => x.TryGetLicence(It.Is<Predicate<Licence>>(/* add your specific condition for licence1 */ ))).Returns(lic1);
mockAgent.Setup(x => x.TryGetLicence(It.Is<Predicate<Licence>>(/* add your specific condition for licence2 */ ))).Returns(lic2);
```